configure profile in the run command line with spring boot packaged docker image with maven
I have several profiles defined in my application.yml of my spring boot application and I don't know how to activate them when running my docker image. The idea is that I will have different environment (IST, UAT, PROD) and depending on the environment the variables will change (mostly server addresses, ports and connection info needed within the app).
The difficulty I have is to load the correct profile for spring boot. Normally I would add, in the java command line, the following option -Dspring.profiles.active=$env. The problem is that my spring boot application is build into a docker image using the spring-boot-maven-plugin by executing "mvn spring-boot:build-image".
And the image that is built has the following entrypoint : "/cnb/process/web" instead of a java command line. I suppose that the option -Dspring.profiles.active can be added in the pom.xml in the  section. But I have no idea where...
Also I would like the variable $env (name of the profile) overrided when I run the image (with a -e parameter in the docker run).
Any ideas?
Best regards,
Thomas
I have no idea how to do that

You can set a SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable, which might be easier here.  More generally, you can provide individual Spring property values via environment variables, which will generally be more maintainable than trying to build every possible environment's settings into the single jar file you're using.  You also may be able to inject an out-of-tree YAML or properties file.
